# SCDF sample local configuration for Multiplatform support

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Currently I see we can run tasks across multiple platform in SCDF. I see samples for Kubernetes and CF.
https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/multi-platform-deployment/multi-platform-task/

Do we have similar example for local deployment? I am looking for     Deployment of tasks across different physical servers using local deployment ( we are not using container as of now )

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by defining `spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.local.accounts` entries (cf. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-local-tasks)

You also have a sample in the mentioned article (https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/multi-platform-deployment/multi-platform-task/#configuring-spring-cloud-data-flow-1)

```
export SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON="{\"spring.cloud.dataflow.task\":{\"platform.kubernetes.accounts\":{\"kzone\":{\"namespace\" : \"default\"}},\"platform.cloudfoundry.accounts\":{\"cfzone\":{\"connection\":{\"url\":\"https://myconnection\",\"domain\":\"mydomain\",\"org\":\"myorg\",\"space\":\"myspace\",\"username\":\"admin\",\"password\":\"password\",\"skipSslValidation\":true},\"deployment\":{\"deleteRoutes\":false,\"services\":\"garsql,atscheduler\",\"enableRandomAppNamePrefix\":false,\"memory\":3072},\"schedulerProperties\":{\"schedulerUrl\":\"https://scheduler.cf.navy.springapps.io\"}}}}}{\"spring.cloud.dataflow.task\":{\"platform.kubernetes.accounts\":{\"kzone\":{\"namespace\" : \"default\"}}}}{\"spring.cloud.dataflow.task\":{\"platform.local.accounts\":{\"local\":{\"timeout\" : \"60\"}}}}"
```

Here the interesting part :

```
{
    "spring.cloud.dataflow.task": {
        "platform.local.accounts": {
            "local": {
                "timeout": "60"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see a place to mention the server name in the properties.

Comment: In the sample above, the server name is "local".
If you follow my first link, you'll see an example addressing 2 servers named "localDev" and "localDevDebug".